# declaring a javascript variable with condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a problem. I want to create a string (variable) in `JS`, using conditions, as follows:

```
var seanceHtml = '<table>' +
    '<tr><td>{{ Lang::get("messages.Monday") }}</td><td></td></tr>' +
        $.each(seances, function (index, seance)
        {

            if(seance.day == 0)
            {
                if(typeof seance.start_date === 'undefined' && typeof seance.end_date === 'undefined')
                {
                    <td><a><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></a></td>
                }
            }
        }) +
    '<tr><td>{{ Lang::get("messages.Tuesday") }}</td><td></td></tr>' +
    '<tr><td>{{ Lang::get("messages.Wednesday") }}</td><td></td></tr>' +
    '<tr><td>{{ Lang::get("messages.Thursday") }}</td><td></td></tr>' +
    '<tr><td>{{ Lang::get("messages.Friday") }}</td><td></td></tr>' +
    '<tr><td>{{ Lang::get("messages.Saturday") }}</td><td></td></tr>' +
    '</table>';
```

It said I have a problem in the syntax.

Comment: Where does it say you have a problem with the syntax? What is the exact error?

Comment: $.each returns an object, not a string.  Close your string, add to it in the middle of the if, and then start adding to the string after you're done.  Or use $.map().join().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the concatenation inside the `jQuery.each()` function like the following.

```
var seanceHtml = '<table>' +
         '<tr><td>{{ Lang::get("messages.Monday") }}</td><td></td></tr>';
$.each(seances, function (index, seance) {
    if(seance.day == 0) {
        if(typeof seance.start_date === 'undefined' && typeof seance.end_date === 'undefined') {
            seanceHtml += '<td><a><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></a></td>';
        }
    }
});
seanceHtml += '<tr><td>{{ Lang::get("messages.Tuesday") }}</td><td></td></tr>' +
    '<tr><td>{{ Lang::get("messages.Wednesday") }}</td><td></td></tr>' +
    '<tr><td>{{ Lang::get("messages.Thursday") }}</td><td></td></tr>' +
    '<tr><td>{{ Lang::get("messages.Friday") }}</td><td></td></tr>' +
    '<tr><td>{{ Lang::get("messages.Saturday") }}</td><td></td></tr>' +
    '</table>';
```

See this demo.

```js
seances = [{start_date : 'asdasdasd', end_date : 'asdasdasd', day : 0 },{start_date : 'asdasdasd', end_date : 'asdasdasd'},{start_date : 'asdasdasd', end_date : 'asdasdasd'}];

seanceHtml = '<table>' +
         '<tr><td>{{ Lang::get("messages.Monday") }}</td><td></td></tr>';
$.each(seances, function (index, seance) {
    if(seance.day == 0) {
        if(typeof seance.start_date === 'undefined' && typeof seance.end_date === 'undefined') {
            seanceHtml += '<td><a><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></a></td>';
        }
    }
});
seanceHtml += '<tr><td>{{ Lang::get("messages.Tuesday") }}</td><td></td></tr>' +
    '<tr><td>{{ Lang::get("messages.Wednesday") }}</td><td></td></tr>' +
    '<tr><td>{{ Lang::get("messages.Thursday") }}</td><td></td></tr>' +
    '<tr><td>{{ Lang::get("messages.Friday") }}</td><td></td></tr>' +
    '<tr><td>{{ Lang::get("messages.Saturday") }}</td><td></td></tr>' +
    '</table>';


document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = seanceHtml;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
```

Comment: Could you indicate *where* and *what* the error was so OP can learn from his mistake?

Comment: @MikeC I am adding the details.

Comment: the error is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }" is the line inside the second if statement.

Comment: @MoslemCherif that was because we missed the apostrophe for the text inside each loop.

Comment: Same problem always with this solution

Comment: What is the value for `seances`?

Comment: it's ok !
Man u r great really